# Add TapRecognizer and different color to word inside a string in Xcode

Tags: ios, nsstring, uigesturerecognizer

I am pulling a text from a plist and draw it into a UIView. 
The text contains terms that I want to be highlighted and user interaction enabled so I could pop a dictionary view with the teem explanation.

I know how to find their location on the string and that works fine. 
But I did not find how to make them a appear in different color. 
And even more important to me - how to add a tap recognizer to them.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks 
Shani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.k
i found a solution that works great for me.

i am using UIWebView as The view for the text and then adds the text formatted as HTML.
in this way i can use CSS to format the text better and even tag some of the text as link ,in the example i want that the word consonant will appear as a link.
(an other great benefit is that I can add support to RTL languishes).

```
UIWebView *webView =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:imgViewRect];
            webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            webView.opaque=NO;
            webView.delegate=self;
            NSString *localizedPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rt%@",pcard.card_number];
            NSString *localizedString = NSLocalizedString(localizedPath,@"");
            NSString *cssPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"style" ofType:@"css"];

            //do base url for css
            NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
            NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

            NSString *html =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"consonant\"><dfn>consonant</dfn></a>",
                             currentLanguage,dir,cssPath,langClass,localizedString];
            NSLog(@"%@",html);
            [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];  

            [self addSubview:webView];
```

then i use this function to recognize what word clicks and lunch a UIView with the dictionary text:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {  
        NSURL *URL = [request URL];  
        NSLog(@"%@",[URL lastPathComponent]); //thats gives me the name of the clicked word. 


        //here you can set any function that you like.
            //using the data from the url path.

    }
    return YES;
}
```

hope it will help someone.
shani

Answer (score 0):

Add a transparent button with the same font and text in front of where the word appears in the UIView. I have a class that will do this with a UILabel if you'd like it? It creates the same effect as with the Facebook application.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. isn't there away to effect the text itself? in any case i would love to see your class it might save me some working time. thanks again

Comment: sure... you would need to use attributed strings (which you'll have to go down to Core text level to achieve). I'll find the link to my class... its not mine personally, I just use it. :)